# Trying to add new worksheets in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add 5 new worksheets in my vba code. Originally my code only required 1 sheet and now 6 sheets need to be present. Each have a unique name. I will have different lines of code throughout the code that need to be added to each worksheet.

```
Sheets(1).Name = "Make-Ready"
Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(1)).Name = "My New Worksheet"
Set MRBook = Worksheets("Make-Ready").Parent
```

There is a portion of the code that errors out when my variable MRBook is defined.

```
If (RDBook.Sheets("RawData").Cells(PoleRow - 12, "BZ").Value) = "No" Then MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready").Range(Cells(PoleRow, 87), Cells(PoleRow, 88)).Style = "Bad"
```

The part that errors out is the MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready"). Do you know which part of these two examples could be the issue?

Comment: what error are is it giving you?

Comment: How did you declare `MRBook`?

Comment: @MilesFett It gives me an application defined or objected defined error. It highlihgts everything to the right of Then on my second code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Public PoleRow As XlRowCol
Public MRBook, RDBook As Workbook

Comment: Hmmm. So `MRBook` is a variant. But that shouldn't cause the error.  In the immediate window, type `?MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready").Range(Cells(PoleRow, 87), Cells(PoleRow, 88)).Address` and also `MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready").Range(Cells(PoleRow, 87), Cells(PoleRow, 88)).Worksheet.Name` and see if it returns the expected parameters.

Comment: Cells is an implicit reference, I think it is trying to set a range in ```MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready")``` from cells in ```RDBook.Sheets("RawData")```. If you do ```MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready").Range(MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready").Cells(PoleRow, 87), MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready").Cells(PoleRow, 88))``` it might work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not qualifying `Cells` properly.  By that I mean that in the `Then` line, the `Cells` keyword is not referring to the proper worksheet.

`Cells` (unqualified) references the active worksheet.  So your program should work if `Make-Ready` happens to be the active worksheet.

In the code below, because of the `With..` and the leading dot, `Cells` will reference  `Make-Ready` no matter what worksheet is active.

Try:

```
With MRBook.Sheets("Make-Ready")

    If (RDBook.Sheets("RawData").Cells(PoleRow - 12, "A").Value) = "No" Then .Range(.Cells(PoleRow, 87), .Cells(PoleRow, 88)).Style = "Bad"

End With
```

As pointed out by @EEM,

```
If (RDBook.Sheets("RawData").Cells(PoleRow - 12, "A").Value) = "No" Then Range(.Cells(PoleRow, 87), .Cells(PoleRow, 88)).Style = "Bad"
```

*(no dot preceding `Range`)* would also work since both arguments are qualified by the worksheet.

Comment: For the same reason, there is no need for the `.` in the `Range`, it could just be: `Range(.Cells(PoleRow, 87), .Cells(PoleRow, 88)).Style = "Bad"`. The `.` would be needed in cases when the `Range` is "made" using a "label" not `cells` (i.e. `.Range("DATA")`, or `.Range("A1:Z10")`.

Comment: @EEM Agree, but it doesn't hurt.  Will add a note.